# asp.net and vb.net code for sending emails to multiple email address via smtp

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email, smtp

I am a new in coding asp.net and vb.net. I have a web form built with asp.net and vb.net .

In the front end of the there are four fields constructed as below.

**Recipient Mailing List :** Drop down List (the options in the drop down list are such as  Managers, HR, Admin, IT etc.  Each option name contains multiple email addresses. i.e selecting one option means The user selects one group of of email address in the recipient field )

**From Field :** Text box (Read Only )

**Subject :**    Text box

**Message :**    Textarea

**Send email button**

The asp.net front end code is like below.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">

<div class="aux-body">
    <div class="aux-body-content">

                <div class="form-element">
                    <label>Recipient Mailing list  </label>
                    <select runat="server" class="" id="comMailingList" datatextfield="name" datavaluefield="id"></select>
                 </div>

                <div class="form-element">
                    <label> From </label>
                    <input style="width: 98%;" runat="server" id="txtFrom" type="text" value="Careers portal" readonly="readonly" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-element">
                    <label> Subject </label>
                    <input style="width: 98%;" runat="server" id="txtSubject"  class="msubject" type="text" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-element">
                    <label> Message </label>
                    <textarea style="width: 98%; height: 100px;" runat="server" id="txtText"  ></textarea>

                </div>

                <div id="button-group">
                     <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnSend" CssClass="btn" Text="Send Email"></asp:LinkButton>
                </div>


    </div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

In the back end  i have structured the VB.net code like following. But i am unable to write the code that will send the email.

```
Partial Class E4_Candidate_broadcast
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page





Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        If Not IsNothing(Request("b")) Then
            cid.Value = Request("b")
        End If
        litMyEmail.Text = UserEmail
        comMailingList.DataSource = Lists
        comMailingList.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub


Public ReadOnly Property Lists() As DataTable
    Get
        Return DB.GetData("select   ml.id, ml.name + ' (' + cast( count(mlc.mailinglistid) as nvarchar(10)) + ' contacts)' name from mailinglist ml join mailinglistcontact mlc     on ml.id = mlc.mailinglistid where ml.deleted = 0 and ml.createdby in (select userid from employeruser where employerid = @eid) group by ml.id, ml.name having count(mlc.mailinglistid) > 0 order by ml.name", DB.SIP("eid", LocalHelper.UserEmployerID()))
    End Get
End Property



Protected Sub btnSend_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtSubject.Value) Then



        ''Selects the recipients name and email address 

        Dim contacts = DB.GetData("select title, name, surname, email from mailinglistcontact where mailinglistid = @mlid", DB.SIP("mlid", comMailingList.Value)), _
 mailers = New DataTable(), _
 mailerqueue = New DataTable(), _
        scheduleat = Now


        For Each contact As DataRow In contacts.Rows

           ''''Code for sending email''''


        Next



        Response.Redirect("broadcast-sent-complete.aspx?i=" & cbId)

    End If
End Sub


End Class
```

I have seen several examples by googling and found several  links. But I am surely not understanding many things which are essential to code for sending emails.

I will be very much obliged if you help me write the code to send emails.

Thank you

Update

I have tried the following code. but its not working. i.e. the email is not sending.the code is going to the exception and saying message sending mailed. please have a look at my code  and point me my error.

```
Dim message As New MailMessage()
        For Each contact As DataRow In contacts.Rows

            Try
                Dim Client As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient

                With Client
                    If WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("smtpserver").Length > 0 Then
                        .DeliveryMethod = Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory 'Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
                        .PickupDirectoryLocation = "c:/outbox/"
                        .Host = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("smtpserver")
                    Else
                        .DeliveryMethod = Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis
                    End If

                    With message
                        Dim FromAddress As MailAddress = New MailAddress("noreply@mypeoplebiz.com")
                        .From = FromAddress
                        .[To].Add(contact.Item("email").ToString())
                        .Subject = txtSubject.Value
                        .IsBodyHtml = True
                        .Priority = MailPriority.Normal
                        .BodyEncoding = Encoding.Default

                        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtHtml.Value) Then
                            .Body = txtHtml.Value
                        End If


                        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtText.Value) Then
                            .Body = txtText.Value
                        End If
                    End With



                    .Send(message)
                End With

            Catch Ex As Exception
                _error = Ex.Message
            End Try


        Next
```

Comment: I've a feeling this will be downvoted/closed pretty soon as you are showing no research effort etc. Seriously, just google it there are hundreds of examples of sending email using vb.net (https://www.google.co.uk/#safe=off&q=sending+email+using+vb.net) if you get stuck on a particular problem, post a new question and we can help you out.

Comment: please see my updated question to see what i have tried so far.